# Get Current User Firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase

Like many developers I am migrating my backend away from Parse after the announcement this week and I can't figure out how to get check if there is currently a user logged in or not. I am using email and password authentication.

Here is my code which does not work:

```
public class ApplicationStart extends Application {


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    Firebase ref = new Firebase(Passwords.FB_LINK);
    AuthData currentUser = ref.getAuth();
    if (currentUser == null) {
        // Take user to log in screen
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyIntro.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else {
        // User already logged in
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(Passwords.TWITTER_KEY, Passwords.TWITTER_SECRET);
    Fabric.with(this, new TwitterCore(authConfig), new Digits());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I managed to figure this out shortly after posting this question. Here is the code that worked. I only needed to change one line:

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase(Passwords.FB_LINK).child("users");
```

Full Code:

```
public class ApplicationStart extends Application {


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    Firebase ref = new Firebase(Passwords.FB_LINK).child("users");
    AuthData currentUser = ref.getAuth();
    if (currentUser == null) {
        // Take user to log in screen
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyIntro.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else {
        // User already logged in
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(Passwords.TWITTER_KEY, Passwords.TWITTER_SECRET);
    Fabric.with(this, new TwitterCore(authConfig), new Digits());
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null` a more simple solution?

Comment: @Gonzalo should add this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

From [Firebase Auth Quickstart](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start/):

Declare an instance (class variable)

```
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
```

In `onCreate()` initialize `mAuth`

```
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

In `onStart()` check if the user is signed in and check for `null`

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if (currentUser == null) {
        // No user is signed in
    } else {
        // User logged in
    }
}
```

This can be done with one liner:

```
if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()) {
   //User is logged in
}
```